# $P(A+B=1|B+C=1)$ if $A,B,C$ i.i.d

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I want to compute $P(A+B=1|B+C=1)$ if $P(A=1) = P(B=1) = P(C=1)= P(A=0) = P(B=0) = P(C=0) = 1/2$ and $A,B,C$ i.i.d.

My attempt:

$P(A+B=1|B+C=1) \\= P(A+B = 1 | B=1, C=0) + P(A+B = 1 | B = 0, C = 1) \\=P(A=0|B=1,C=0) + P(A=1|B=0,C=1) = 1/2 + 1/2 = 1$

But somehow this does not look correct to me.

Edit: Furthermore I want 4 $P(A+B=2 | B+C = 1)$. Is it $\frac{P(A=1 \land B=1 \land C = 0)}{P(B=1 \land C=0)} = 1/4$

Comment: Your attempt seems based on the false belief that $$P(A\mid B_1\cup B_2)=P(A\mid B_1)+P(A\mid B_2)$$ when $B_1$ and $B_2$ are disjoint. Quite untrue in général, please check the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the definition
$$P(A+B=1|B+C=1) = \frac{P(A+B=1 \mbox{ and } B+C=1)}{P(B+C=1)}$$

The event $\{A+B=1 \mbox{ and } B+C=1\}$ occurs if and only if $A=C=1$ and $B=0$ or $A=C=0$ and $B=1$. Then its probability is $(1/2)^3+(1/2)^3 = 1/4$.

The event $\{B+C=1\}$ occurs if and only if $B=1$ and $C=0$ or $B=0$ and $C=1$. Then its probability is $(1/2)^2+(1/2)^2 = 1/2$.

So
$$P(A+B=1|B+C=1) = \frac{P(A+B=1 \mbox{ and } B+C=1)}{P(B+C=1)} = \frac{1/4}{1/2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: How about $P(A+B=2 | B+C = 1)$?

Comment: Is this a new question?

Answer (score 4):

If $A + B = 1$ then it is clear that $A = \text{not}(B)$. So

$$P(A = \text{not}(B) \,| B = \text{not}(C)) = P(A = C) = \frac{1}{2}$$

because we are considering $B$ that is different from $C$ and there is a 50:50 chance that this $B$ is not equal to $A$

Answer (score 1):

If $B+C=1$, either $B = 1$ and $C = 0$, or $B = 0$ and $C = 1$. Both scenarios are equally likely, and thus have a probability of $\frac{1}{2}.$ In the former case, A must be 0 in order for $A+B=1$, which has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}.$ In the latter case, A must be 1 in order for $A+B=1$, which again has a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$. In probability theory, it holds that:

$$P[A\,|\,B] = P[A\,|\,C] \cdot P[C\,|\,B] + P[A\,|\,\neg C] \cdot P[\neg C\,|\,B]$$

In our case, this translates to:

$$P[A+B=1|B+C=1] = P[A = 0|B = 1,C = 0] \cdot P[B = 1,C = 0|B + C = 1] + P[A = 1|B = 0,C = 1] \cdot P[B = 0,C = 1|B + C = 1] = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$$

It is worth noting that we can use [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) as well to solve this problem, as already illustrated in a previous answer.